# Plotting multi-indexed data

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, multi-index

So i'm currently working on a program that takes data from an xlsx file, generates a set of plots  (two pie charts, one table and a bar chart combined with a line chart) for each client in the xlsx file and then makes a slide in powerpoint with those plots for each one of the clients. In order for this whole operation to work as a loop i have used multi indexes. The core of the problem is that the labels on the x-axis of the bar chart (which shows performance by month) print out the whole multi index (the name, the year and the month). My question is, how can i get the labels to show only the date without the name. The other charts show what they are intended to.
So sorry that i did not paste any pictures or a piece of the code. I'm using corporate data.
The library that i have used to make the charts is matplotlib.

Maybe i should try some kind of a workaround with the labels or just using a different library.

Comment: You're going to have to share some code. Write a small example code that reproduces the problem. See [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: i expect this question might get downvoted. here is a guide for how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask